# Skipped 773 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. [ANDROID WEBVIEW]

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, webview, android-webview

I have an app that is a webview app. It load's a HTML page where I use some JS and Jquery. But lately I got this warning on a emulator:

> Skipped 773 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>
> Suspending all threads took: 14.255ms
>
> Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38341(1813KB)
> AllocSpace objects, 8(160KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 11MB/11MB, paused
> 46.590ms total 800.341ms
>
> Suspending all threads took: 35.225ms
>
> Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
>
> Suspending all threads took: 224.946ms
>
> Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 100(3KB) AllocSpace
> objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 25% free, 11MB/15MB, paused 65.153ms total
> 423.872ms
>
> Suspending all threads took: 19.208ms
>
> Skipped 152 frames!  The
> application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

And this keeps going until it the index.html loads.

This is MainActivity.java:

```
    package checker.coin.crypto.wingcrony.by.cryptocoinchecker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); //try js alert
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support


    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("sms:") || url.startsWith("smsto:") || url.startsWith("mailto:") || url.startsWith("mms:") || url.startsWith("mmsto:") || url.startsWith("market:") || url.equals("http://wingcrony.com/?actie=donate")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack(); //method goback()
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Is there away to multieThread a webview or anything to let it work faster?

Comment: Try moving the very first `loadUrl` to background task. This might be what it's complaining about.

Comment: Can you explain or link me to an example because I don't know much about how to load it in the background. Like you see it only needs to load one url nothing more

Comment: Here is what I'm referring to: [Android:AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This can be used to offload that part into a different thread so main thread doesn't skip frames and keeps chugging along.

Comment: Note, however, that it might be entirely OK for main thread to skip frames if you don't expect your user to be able to do in time while operation executes.

Comment: So maybe work with a splashscreen so it load's in the background and then you show the html page?

Comment: yes, splash should work for that even without background task - users usually understand that app will be loading at that time, and won't try to mash controls (unless load is very long).

Comment: `loadUrl` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a splashscreen to improve the speed.

```
view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        });
```